# Open source well information viewer

Tags: geology, geophysics, seismology, seismic, software

I am in the middle of a hobbyist experiment and would like suggestions on an open source HTML viewer for mud loggging, FMIs, lithology and seismic. I have used INT before but for this project I would like an open source alternative.

Answer (score 2):

**Your best bet is probably [OpendTect](https://dgbes.com/).**

It's not quite what you asked for. OpendTect is a desktop application and does not use HTML/JavaScript for display. It is dual licensed; the free version is licensed under the GPL. It will read wells and seismic no problem, but I'm not sure about FMI in the free version.

Agile started [G3.js](https://github.com/agile-geoscience/g3), a JavaScript library based on D3.js for logs and seismic, but we didn't get very far. (I'm the founder of Agile; I'd welcome a reason to start that project up again.) Agile also has [welly](https://github.com/agile-geoscience/welly), a Python library for well logs and lithology.

There are lists of other open source tools for [geophysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_geophysics_software) and [geology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_geology_software) on Wikipedia.